# GCP - NodeJS - app engine - environment variable

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

complete beginner with Google Cloud Platform here.

I am currently trying to setup a node.js backend API, but I am not able to find out why my environment variables aren't working.

I have one variable with a secret key for JwT authentication and one for my mongoDB Atlas URL.

I have them defined in my app.yaml like it is explained in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#environment_variables

```
    env_variables:
      TOKEN_SECRET: 'MY_SUPER_SECRET_JWT_KEY'
      MONGO_FULL: 'MY_MONGO_URL'
```

But when I try to npm start my application in the shell with `npm start` I get an error:

```
throw new TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a secret or key');
```

Anybody has a clue what I am doing wrong or is there an better way to store and retrieve environment variables in the GCP app engine with node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `npm start` on your local machine, the environment variables from `app.yaml` are not loaded automatically.

Run these in your shell before running `npm start`:

```
export TOKEN_SECRET="MY_SUPER_SECRET_JWT_KEY"
export MONGO_FULL="MY_MONGO_URL"
```

in order to set the environment variables locally.

Comment: Thanks, I just tested it and that was my mistake. 

But I have switched now to Digitalocean because in my opinion its easier to use for my beginner understanding but after this week of learning how to setup a linux server, installing nginx and figuring things out in general about this whole topic I guess there is no real difference to the GCP.